# How to call RESTRequest.ExecuteAsync

Tags: json, rest, delphi

I'm trying to make an async web request using components created at runtime. But I cant get ExecuteAsync method to work: It raises an error : Request has no client component

Here is how to reproduce:

Place an Memo on an empty form an then this code:

```
uses
  REST.Types, REST.Client;

procedure TForm65.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  RESTClient: TRESTClient;
  RESTResponse: TRESTResponse;
  RESTRequest: TRESTRequest;
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;

  RESTClient := TRESTClient.Create('https://dawa.aws.dk/postnumre?nr=9310');
  RESTResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(Self);
  RESTRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(RESTClient);

  RESTRequest.Response := RESTResponse;
  RESTRequest.Execute;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(RESTResponse.Content);


  RESTRequest.ExecuteAsync(
      procedure
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Text := RESTResponse.Content
    end, True, True,
    procedure(AObject: TObject)
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Error: ' + ERESTException(AObject).Message);
    end);

  FreeAndNil(RESTClient);
end;
```

The first synchronized call are just to to show that I get data from that call.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: FreeAndNil will run before executed request.

Comment: You are right. I didn't think about it. 

Put it as an answer and I'll close the question

Comment: Feel free to answer it yourself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dalija Prasnikar pointed me in the right direction: Because the request is executed asynchronously, FreeAndNil will probably run before the request is executed. That will free the client, as well as the request, since the client owns the request.

Mere people said to me that I'm not setting the TRESTRequest.Client property.  That is not correct! Since the Client is the Owner of the Request, the the Client Property are sat in the constructor.

```
{ TCustomRESTRequest }

    constructor TCustomRESTRequest.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
    begin

  // it is important to create the notify-list before
  // calling the inherited constructor
  FNotifyList := TNotifyList.Create;
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  // if we do get a client as owner, we just use
  // it. otherwise we look around and try to find
  // an existing client (maybe on the same form)
  if AOwner is TCustomRESTClient then
    Client := TCustomRESTClient(AOwner)
  else if RESTComponentIsDesigning(Self) then
    Client := RESTFindDefaultClient(Self);

...
```